# Core Data with iCloud import changes takes randomly long time

Tags: core-data, icloud

*Before you down-vote this question, please note that I have already searched Google and asked on Apple Developer Forums but got no solution.*

I am making an app that uses core data with iCloud. Everything is set up fine and the app is saving core data records to the persistent store in the ubiquity container and fetching them just fine.

My problem is that to test if syncing is working fine between two devices (on the same icloud ID), I depend on *NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification* to be fired so that my app (in foreground) can update the table view.

Now it takes random amount of time for this to happen. Sometimes it takes a few seconds and at times even 45 minutes is not enough! I have checked my broadband speed several times and everything is fine there.

I have a simple NSLog statement in the notification handler that prints to the console when the notification is fired, and then proceeds to update the UI.

With this randomly large wait time before changes are imported, I am not able to test my app at all!

Anyone knows what can be done here?

Already checked out related threads...

[More iCloud Core Data synching woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478517/more-icloud-core-data-synching-woes)

[App not syncing Core Data changes with iCloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463851/app-not-syncing-core-data-changes-with-icloud)

PS: I also have 15 GB free space in my iCloud Account.

Comment: I already requested a support instance from Apple which was credited back to my account with Apple saying that its a 'known bug' and that they are working on it.

Comment: Since you already have this reply from Apple, what is your question? You already seem to have a more authoritative answer than anyone on SO can provide.

Comment: my question is "Anyone knows what can be done here?" sorry to be so generic, but my app is stuck since i cannot test it. and doing the exact same thing with the store in icloud throws validation errors and not when the store is local. but before i can dive down into debugging the problem, i have to wait another 45-60 minutes and sometimes forever before a new set of Managed Objects are saved to or deleted from the store!

Comment: these validation errors happen only when importing changes. so like i add a new record, everything syncs fine to the peers (if it syns, that is!) and when i delete it on a peer, the deletion throws no error on that peers but importing the changes throws validation errors for non optional relationships on another peer! and this is just one example. there are many more. like getting error (sorry but i think it was error 1570) for importing changes being aborted!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, testing with Core Data + iCloud can be difficult, precisely because iCloud is an asynchronous data transfer, and you have little influence over when that transfer will take place.

If you are working with small changes, it is usually just 10-20 seconds, sometimes faster. But larger changes may get delayed to be batch uploaded by the system. And it is also possible that if you constantly hit iCloud with new changes — which is common in testing — it can throttle back the transfers.

There isn't much you can really do about it. Try to keep your test data small where possible, and don't forget the Xcode debug menu items to force iCloud to sync up in the simulator.

This aspect of iCloud file sync is driving a lot of developers to use CloudKit, where at least you have a synchronous line of communication, removing some of the uncertainty. But setting up CloudKit takes a lot of custom code, or moving to a non-Apple sync solution.

Comment: what would u mean by small/large changes? i am talking about a single set of record added to the store which has at most 2 ManagedObjects each with just one attribute, an nsnumber and nsdate, respectively. that isn't big at all i guess. i have designed my app to handle much more than this in a single record (about 7 entities with various attributes in each).

Comment: for the life of me i couldnt figure out how i could set up cloudkit to work with core data. cloudkit is too confusing to me.

Comment: fortunately in my app since very few users would require to access their data from multiple devices, i could drop the idea of 'icloud with core data' and use icloud document storage to back up the store file on a scheduled basis and offer manual backup and restore to the user. sync is not THAT important. i was wondering if it is a good idea to just backup the store file to icloud? my concern is that over the years of use the store file will get very large (considering the fact that the user would want to use the app daily).

Comment: can u please elaborate on "don't forget the Xcode debug menu items to force iCloud to sync up in the simulator." 

how can i force that on the device? and if i can do that on the simulator too for time being it will help me going further with me project.

Comment: I get this error message randomly...

2015-07-08 15:08:47.781 AppName[1820:348397] __45-[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(439): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 5 - No document at URL)" UserInfo=0x176628b0 {NSDescription=No document at URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x1766c3b0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory",

Comment: Using a document based approach, and putting the doc in iCloud is certainly one of the easier methods, and probably fine for small data. Another is a third party sync framework. There is my Ensembles.io; I've heard Realm.io syncs via CloudKit; and there are new projects on GitHub for Core Data + CloudKit.

Comment: will backing the store to icloud be incremental? that is only back up the changed bits rather than the entire file, each time?

Comment: If you use the document based approach, it is not incremental. It uploads the full data each time. For small data, that is OK, but not if you have quite a bit. The other options I mentioned are incremental.

Comment: the icloud design guide says on page 30 for document storage... "iCloud optimizes future transfers to and from devices. Instead of sending the entire file or file package each time it changes, iCloud sends only the metadata and the pieces that changed."